# Finding time range for column value change in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with eventTime and status as columns as shown below.

```
eventTime           status
2020-03-01 09:00    TRUE
2020-03-01 10:00    TRUE
2020-03-01 11:00    FALSE
2020-03-01 12:00    FALSE
2020-03-01 13:00    TRUE
2020-03-01 14:00    FALSE
```

I need to produce time range during which status remains the same as shown below.

```
startEventTime       endEventTime          status
2020-03-01 09:00     2020-03-01 11:00       TRUE
2020-03-01 11:00     2020-03-01 13:00       FALSE
2020-03-01 13:00     2020-03-01 14:00       TRUE
2020-03-01 14:00     NULL                   FALSE
```

Appreciate if anyone can help on how to do this in query?

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc.)

Comment: Your data sample is inconsistent.  Either endEventTime includes the time up to the point where a change in status occurred (as with output records 1 and 2), or it does not (as with record 3).  Assuming records 1 and 2 are correct, then record 3 should have an endEventTime of 2020-03-01 14:00 when the event status changed from TRUE to FALSE.  Assuming record 3 is correct, then record 1 should have ended at 10:00 and record 2 should have ended at 12:00.  Please clarify.

Comment: I believe what @mitselplik is trying to say is that your desired RESULTS are inconsistent. The end time for the third row should be 14:00, right?

Comment: @Mitselplik Sorry, Corrected the output - changed record 3 output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gap-and-islands problem.  In this version, you seem to want the times to "tile" with no gaps.  For this version, the simplest method is probably `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.eventTime as startTime,
       lead(t.eventTime) over (order by t.eventTime) as endTime,
       t.status
from (select t.*, 
             lag(status) over (order by eventTime) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status;
```

This works by taking the first row where the status changes (using the `lag()`).  When the intermediate rows are filtered out, it gets the next start time for the end time.

Comment: I up-voted Gordon's answer over my own :-) I had completely forgotten about lag() and lead() because I see them so seldom used!  Good answer Gordon :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the answer you are looking for, but this works in T-SQL:

```
declare @data table(eventTime datetime, status varchar(5))
insert into @data (eventTime, status)
values 
('2020-03-01 09:00', 'TRUE'),
('2020-03-01 10:00', 'TRUE'),
('2020-03-01 11:00', 'FALSE'),
('2020-03-01 12:00', 'FALSE'),
('2020-03-01 13:00', 'TRUE'),
('2020-03-01 14:00', 'FALSE')

select 
    startEventTime = min(startEventTime),
    endEventTime,
    status
from (
    select 
        startEventTime = eventStart.eventTime, 
        endEventTime = min(eventEnd.eventTime),
        status = eventStart.status
    from @data as eventStart
    left join @data as eventEnd on 
        eventEnd.eventTime >= eventStart.eventTime and
        eventEnd.status <> eventStart.status
    group by eventStart.eventTime, eventStart.status
) as tmp
group by endEventTime, status
order by 1
```